# How do I turn Redstone into Redstone Dust in Minecraft?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-redstone

I have 28 or so Redstones — not Redstone dust. I mined them with an iron pick. However, all of the things I see say how to use the *dust*, not the stones. How can I turn my Redstones into Redstone dust?

Answer (score 32, accepted):

There is no item actually called “Redstone Dust”; this is a colloquial name for the **[[image] Redstone](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Redstone_Dust)** item, because it has the appearance of a pile or trail of powder. If this is what you have, then you already have the “dust” and you can use it as you have seen discussed.

If you have a stone-like block with red inclusions, then you have **[[image] Redstone Ore](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Redstone_Ore)**. This is not usually the case because it requires an pickaxe [enchanted](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Enchanting) with Silk Touch to obtain without breaking the block. To obtain Redstone from Redstone Ore, simply place the block and then break it with an iron or diamond pickaxe that does *not* have the Silk Touch enchantment. (You can increase the quantity obtained by breaking it with a Fortune enchanted pickaxe.)

Comment: @Joe the Person: (Thanks for wanting to improve the formatting, but I won't stand for semantic abuse of markup. I made sure the images were on the first line of each paragraph.)

Comment: What do you mean "first line of each paragraph)?

Comment: @JoethePerson There are two paragraphs in his answer. I believe he is referring to the first line of each of those paragraphs.

Comment: You should add Redstone Block for sake of completeness (assembled from 9 redstone dusts)

Answer (score 5):

You already have redstone dust. You can place that on the ground to make redstone wire which can be used to make all sorts of different circuits which can be used for different purposes. You can always pick up the redstone wire and put it back into your inventory. When you do that, it is called redstone dust again. [Here is the wiki page on it.](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Redstone_Dust)